# How to convert this method which returns a dictionary from Swift to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

This is the Swift function:

```
private class func sharedDateFormatters() -> [String: NSDateFormatter] {
        struct Static {
            static var formatters: [String: NSDateFormatter]? = nil
            static var once: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.once) {
            Static.formatters = [String: NSDateFormatter]()
        }
        return Static.formatters!
    }
```

Having trouble converting this into modern Objective-C syntax. Looking for an elegant solution.

Tried something along those lines:

```
 + (NSDictionary *) sharedDateFormatters {
    struct Static{
        static NSDictionary *formatters =
    }
}
```

Obviously incorrect.

Comment: 1) It's not an array. 2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tired  -__-   I meant dictionary. Will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused by structs, I believe. This is a trick that was used in Swift 1.0 - 1.1 for creating singletons. It's more straight-forward now with Swift 1.2+.

In Objective-C it would look something like this:

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSDateFormatter *>*)sharedDateFormatters {
    static NSMutableDictionary *dict = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    });
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: Thx! I started with Swift 2.0 and am now learning Objective-C ! I was therefore already using the simpler way to create singletons and never saw this syntax before.

Comment: @CodeOxO, I wish you luck) I have a question about your Swift code: what is the intended way of adding values to `formatters`? I don't get it. The function returns immutable value. There is no setter, obviously. You create an empty dictionary, but how are you going to use it? I'm not a Swift expert (yet :) ), so I might be missing something.

Comment: It's not my code. I am converting a Swift library into Objective-C as an exercise.

Comment: @CodeOxO, oh, I see)